# is there any way to iterate two variables into one table in laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I am beginner in both laravel and php. So, I have two variables and I want to iterate both of them into one table. I want `<p class="text-warning">Izin sudah mau habis!</p>` to be displayed inside `<td>tenggat_izin</td>` column. I tried this but it keeps looping all of them inside the table while i only want one of them which has the value of <31 for each row to display the warning text.

```
<script src="js/tower_kecamatan.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tower_kecamatan.css">
<h2 class="text-center">{{$region->kecamatan}}</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered col-md-12" id="search">
  <thead class="thead-dark" >
      <th scope="col">TOWER</th>
      <th scope="col">ALAMAT</th>
      <th scope="col">PERUSAHAAN</th>
      <th scope="col">KOORDINAT</th>
      <th scope="col">KETINGGIAN</th>
      <th scope="col">PEMILIK TANAH</th>
      <th scope="col">IZIN TOWER</th>
      <th scope="col">TENGGAT IZIN</th>
      <th scope="col">SHELTER DAN GENSET</th>
      <th scope="col">LISTRIK</th>
      <th scope="col">PAGAR TOWER</th>
      <th scope="col">PAPAN NAMA TOWER</th>
      <th scope="col">PETUGAS</th>
      <th scope="col">HP PETUGAS</th>
    </thead>
  
  @foreach ($data as $x)
  <tr>
      <td>{{$x->tower_id}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->desa}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->pemilik_tower}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->koordinat}}<p><a href="{{$x->tower_id}}/foto">lihat gambar</a></p></td>
      <td>{{$x->ketinggian_meter}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->pemilik_tanah}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->izin_tower}}</td>  
      <td>{{$x->tenggat_izin}}
    @foreach ($diff as $y)
      @if ($y < 31)
      <p class="text-warning">Izin sudah mau habis!</p>
      @endif
    @endforeach
      </td>  
      <td>{{$x->shelter_genset}}</td>  
      <td>{{$x->listrik}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->pagar_tower}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->papan_nama}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->petugas}}</td>
      <td>{{$x->hp_petugas}}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: what 2 table you have and what is structure ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. I would add an `@break` to stop checking `$diff` values.

```php
@foreach ($diff as $y)
    @if ($y < 31)
        <p class="text-warning">Izin sudah mau habis!</p>
    @endif
    @break;
@endforeach
```

Comment: tried this but it doesnt work. It does not show anything at all regardless of `diff` value